# Login activity Using Shared Prefrence

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I made login activity using shared preference. Code is below.

I got an error when i login. It always show password is incorrect.

Any body help me to improve the code so that i complete my project.

UserSession Class

```
 package com.achal089.pestcontrol;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by as on 5/7/2016.
 */
public class UserSession {

    SharedPreferences pref;

    // Editor reference for Shared preferences
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Context
    Context _context;

    // Shared preferences mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    public static final String PREFER_NAME = "Register";

    // All Shared Preferences Keys
    public static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

    // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String Email = "Email";

    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String Password = "Password";


    // Constructor
    public UserSession(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    //Create login session
    public void createUserLoginSession(String uName, String uPassword){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

        // Storing name in preferences
        editor.putString(Email, uName);

        // Storing email in preferences
        editor.putString(Password,  uPassword);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Check login method will check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else do anything
     * */
    public boolean checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isUserLoggedIn()){

            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);

            // Closing all the Activities from stack
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){

        //Use hashmap to store user credentials
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // user name
        user.put(Email, pref.getString(Email, null));

        // user email id
        user.put(Password, pref.getString(Password, null));

        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){

        // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to MainActivity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, MainActivity.class);

        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    // Check for login
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
    }
}
```

Login activity

```
package com.achal089.pestcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity {

    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Register";

    UserSession session;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;



    TextView login;
    TextView pass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



     login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.password);


      Button buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        // Login button click event
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Get username, password from EditText
                String username = login.getText().toString();
                String password = pass.getText().toString();

                // Validate if username, password is filled             
                if(username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0){
                    String uName = null;
                    String uPassword =null;

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("Email"))
                    {
                        uName = sharedPreferences.getString("Email", "");

                    }

                    if (sharedPreferences.contains("Password"))
                    {
                        uPassword = sharedPreferences.getString("Password", "");

                    }

                    // Object uName = null;
                    // Object uEmail = null;
                    if(username.equals(uName) && password.equals(uPassword)){

                        session.createUserLoginSession(uName,
                                uPassword);

                        // Starting MainActivity
                        Intent i = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();

                    }else{

                        // username / password doesn't match&
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username/Password is incorrect",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }else{

                    // user didn't entered username or password
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter username and password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });




    }



    public void Reg(View view)
    {
        Intent a = new Intent(Login.this,Register.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }


}
}
```

Register activity

```
package com.achal089.pestcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Register extends Activity {

    UserSession session;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    TextView name;
    TextView address;
    TextView email;
    TextView phone;
    TextView occupation;
    TextView password;
    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Register";

    public static final String Name = "nameKey";
    public static final String Email = "emailKey";
    public static final String Phone = "Phone";
    public static final String Address = "Address";
    public static final String Occupation = "Occupation";
    public static final String Password = "Password";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        occupation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Name)) {
            name.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
        }
        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Email)) {
            email.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Email, ""));

        }

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Occupation)) {
            occupation.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Occupation, ""));
        }

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Password)) {
            password.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Password, ""));
        }


        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Address)) {
            address.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Address, ""));

        }

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(Phone)) {
            phone.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Phone, ""));

        }



    }


    public void Save(View view) {
        String n = name.getText().toString();
        String e = email.getText().toString();
        String w = phone.getText().toString();
        String m = address.getText().toString();
        String p = password.getText().toString();
        String v = occupation.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(Name, n);
        editor.putString(Email, e);
        editor.putString(Phone, w);
        editor.putString(Address,m);
        editor.putString(Occupation,v);
        editor.putString(Password,p);
        editor.commit();


        Intent a = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    public void Login (View view)
    {
        Intent a = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: LoginActivity is same code as UserSession. Please update.

Comment: I update it please help me

Comment: Well, what string is in your SharedPreferences? It doesn't come with a string already there...

Comment: In your login, you have used a different name("Register") for shared preference than the name that you have used in your register("mypref"). So, the values that are always retrieved for uname and password from shared preferences in login activity will be "". I think this might be the problem why you are always getting username/password didn't match. Once check it.

Comment: just change the name of the shared preference in your Register activity to "Register"

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using the UserSession class appropriately.

You've done this

```
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And used a SharedPreferences different than the `session` variable and the login activity (the string parameters do not match). Plus, the session variable appears to be entirely unused in the register activity code and not used correctly in the login activity

You can use it like

```
session = new UserSession(getApplicationContext());
```

Inside the onCreate of both classes. You don't need a SharedPreferences object in either class.

You can use either way of matching the strings you used to define the SharedPreferences, or you can actually use the UserSession code. That decision is up to you, but I would suggest not mixing the two.

You may also want to go back over [the tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) where that code is from to see its full usage.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Login** activity, you have retrieved "Register" shared preference, which you thought you have initialized the user name and password in your **Register** class. But, in your **Register** class:

```
public static final String mypreference = "mypref";//this name is different
```

In your **Login** class, you have used:

```
private static final String PREFER_NAME = "Register";
```

This is why you will always get default values when you retrieve uname and password from Register shared preferences in your Login activity and the validation will always give you false. In your **Register** class, change the name of the shared preference to "Register".